# Running into a few problems after updating Microsoft.Graph and Microsoft.Graph.Core - looking to replace these code snippets

Tags: c#, vb.net, microsoft-graph-api, nuget-package, microsoft-graph-teams

We have created software to integrate with Microsoft Teams, using the Microsoft.Graph packages from NuGet.

Up until recently these were working fine even while Microsoft regularly updated its NuGet packages. We had no problem with Microsoft.Graph 4.54.0 and Microsoft.Graph.Core 2.0.15

Today I discovered that Microsoft have now released NuGet Packages Microsoft.Graph 5.0.0 and Microsoft.Graph.Core 3.0.0 so I tried updating these packages but now they are throwing errors when I tried to rebuild the project. Please forgive the use of VB.NET as I'm not responsible for the language in which this was written...

```
        'Create a group in MS Teams
        Dim group = New Group With {
            .Description = teamDescription,
            .DisplayName = teamName,
            .GroupTypes = New List(Of String)() From {
                "Unified"
            },
            .MailEnabled = True,
            .MailNickname = LibraryKey,
            .SecurityEnabled = False,
            .Visibility = If(IsPrivateTeam, "Private", "Public")
        }
        Dim data = Await graphClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(group)
```

The snippet of code above leads to two errors:

1. Type 'Group' is not defined and
2. 'Request' is not a member of 'GroupsRequestBuilder'

The other problematic code snippet is:

```
            Dim team = New Team With {
               .GuestSettings = New TeamGuestSettings With {
               .AllowCreateUpdateChannels = False,
               .AllowDeleteChannels = False,
               .ODataType = Nothing
                },
            .ODataType = Nothing
            }
```

Which leads to a very similar error:

Type 'Team' is not defined.

I am hoping that these can easily be replaced with variations that are compatible with Microsoft.Graph 5.0.0 c.q. Microsoft.Graph.Core 3.0.0 ? I'll be happy with suggestions in C# which I will gladly convert to VB.NET myself

Comment: Did you perform a clean build?  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-overview?force_isolation=true

Comment: I'm not changing from Azure AD to Microsoft Graph. We have been using Microsoft Graph for a couple of years now. We are merely updating Microsoft.Graph from 4.54.0 to 5.0.0 and Microsoft.Graph.Core from 2.0.15 to 3.0.0

Comment: See release notes : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/releases

Comment: Yes I found that but I find that documentation impenetrable. I actually found a page that seemed to deal with creating a group, promptly lost it and now I can't find it anymore :(

Comment: Ahh found it again: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer - from there I navigated to "Groups" in the navigation bar on the left, and found the POST method for creating a new group. What I lack is the ability to "translate" what I am seeing there into a change in the code I posted. Remember, I didn't write this code; I've merely been tasked with modifying it.

Comment: here's the [upgrade document](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md) which at least mention that there's no `Request()` anymore

Comment: Sure, but what it doesn't tell me is what to replace Dim data = Await graphClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(group) with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using GraphAPI package at 5.0, and groups/Teams is all I'm coding for, this works for me, in current Graph client-config:
(with similar var names/syntax)

```
 Dim group = New Group With {
      .Description = teamDescription,
      .DisplayName = teamName,
      .GroupTypes = New List(Of String)() From {
          "Unified"
       },
       .MailEnabled = True,
       .MailNickname = LibraryKey,
       .SecurityEnabled = False,
       .Visibility = If(IsPrivateTeam, "Private", "Public")
     }
 
    Dim data = Await graphClient.Groups.PostAsync(group)
```

sorry this is coming 2-months later

Comment: Better late than never, thanks Sean! I handed this over to our colleagues in India who worked out a solution, I believe, but I hope your answer will help somebody else who may come up against the same thing. Cheers!